# Inject App Insights for Custom Events and Metrics

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-application-insights

What is the "right" way to use [custom events and metrics for app insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics) in ASP.NET Core with dependency injection?  Is there a way to inject `TelemetryClient`?

Everything I can find instantiates the `TelemetryClient` directly and `TelemetryClient` doesn't implement an interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TelemetryClient is automatically injected to DI when you configure Application Insights using either `.UseApplicationInsights()` or `AddApplicationInsights()` methods. You can use constructor injection to get the `TelemetryClient` instance as shown below.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private TelemetryClient telemetry;

    public HomeController(TelemetryClient telemetry)
    {
        this.telemetry = telemetry;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        this.telemetry.TrackEvent("HomePageRequested");
        return View();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Custom-Configuration#track-custom-traceeventmetric

Comment: I found 2 ways one could test `telemetryClient`: 1. Wrap `telemetryClient` into a custom class and inject that into your services. 2. Create fake telemetryChannel as per following article:  https://medium.com/@jrolstad/unit-testing-and-microsoft-application-insights-6db0929b39e6

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure you need to do dependency injection for that part.

other dependency injected stuff, like `.UseApplicationInsights()` does the work to ensure application insights is configured, etc.

after that, code that would do custom events or metrics normally create a `TelemetryClient` on demand, set shared context on the instance, and then write events/metrics *through* it, via the `TrackEvent`, `TrackMetric`, etc methods.  Presuming AI is correctly configured in other places, those new telemetry client instances will have other shared/preconfigured/injected settings ready to go.

Comment: Seems to go against the grain of injecting dependencies, no?  And I wonder how will it behave in unit tests?  Appreciate the response, BTW, thanks !

Comment: true, but if there isn't an interface for telemetryclient (not sure why there isn't, actually), it isn't something that's "well" injected, since it isn't something to easily replace.